# Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.+

Tags: android, android-studio

So, everything was working fine not to long ago but when I tried to make a full screen activity in Android Studio, I get 2 errors.

This appears to only be happening with the full screen activity.

1. Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.+
2. Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g editing, debugging) will not work correctly.

error images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2qdE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wDOa.png

Build error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>    there was 2 links here but I had to remove them because I don't have enough rep.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication2:app:unspecified

Things I have tried:

Installing fresh SDK and Android Studio.
Installing newer versions of java JDK. (I needed a new one anyway)
Google search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

And check if you install Support Library and Support Repository:
[image]

Comment: Here is my build.gradle http://pastebin.com/qWz8thRe I selected everything in the sdk manager so, I'm sure I did.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you good sir. I would give you rep but, I don't have enough rep to do so!